# How to convert old java code to java project with package?

Tags: java, ide

I have a src directory which has many subfolders recursively.
Each folder has multiple java codes which don’t have `package ...` in the first line.
For example, I have  `src/src1/test1/org1/back1/Test1.java`

```
// there is no package src1.test1.org1.back1; in the first line of code
class Test1 {...}
```

I want to add for example `package src1.test1.org1.back1;` for the above `Test.java` in the first line of each java files.But there are so many java code and can’t do manually.

Is there a way to insert `package …` in the first line of each java code based on its directory structure automatically via IDE or something else?

Comment: src1 sould not be a package name

Comment: Eclipse (and other IDEs) offer very good refactoring tools. You can import all java files and move them to the desired package. The IDE will then put hte package declaration into the file. If you already have a packge, Drag+Drop might also work, depending on the used IDE.